# insert into a table with varchar column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have defined `Code` as a column in a table as `varchar`.

When I am trying to insert `'123cb4'`, an error occurs:

> it isn't possible insert int into a varchar character

I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Add your `insert script` in question

Comment: Could you post your Insert Script and table script.

Comment: Have you precise the length of the varchar column? might be that the length is preventing the insertion.

Comment: Although i try it like  INSERT INTO TBL1 (CODE) VALUES (123)                and it still works fine

Comment: What is the error message? Providing details like that is kind of important, it let us know what your error was. It might be a foreign key violation or something completely different and unrelated to what you think. Post the insert statement AND the error message and we can help you figure this out quickly. Without those details the best we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine

code  -->  VARCHAR(50)

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 (CODE) VALUES ('123cb4')
```